# Compile Error on Autofilter by Dynamic Date

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error when trying to run a macro which should filter my data based on the date in Column AN. I want this to be date dependent, so it should filter everything from 2 months prior to today's date in time.

```
Sub Move2017()
Macro 2017 Clear
Dim DQ As Date
DQ = dateserial(Year(Now), month(Now) - 2, 1)
Range("A1:AZ100000").AutoFilter field:=40, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, DQ)
End Sub
```

I keep getting the following error:
 "Compile Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Range("A1:AZ100000").AutoFilter field:=40, Criteria1:=">="&DQ, Operator:=xlAnd
```

Tested and works for me.

Comment: @NeilD137 you might give Scott credit and mark as "ANSWER" (I've seen you haven't done it so far with previous posts, do you know how ?)

Comment: Actually, if you could tell me how to, I will be sure to do that going forward

Comment: @NeilD137 - There's a grey check mark next to the answer text on the top right, below the voting buttons. Click that check mark :). If you want to answer past questions you can view your profile and click on Questions. Then go to each one and tick the answer. You'll gain rep by doing so if that matters to you.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case @Scott Holtzman solution doesn't work, sometimes the `AutoFilter` with `Date`s can be tricky, depends exactly how you formatted the Cells. In some scenarios it works better with `Double`.

Also, you can use `DateAdd` function much easier to get a date 2 month prior to Today's date.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Move2017()

Dim DQ As Double

DQ = DateAdd("m", -2, Date) '<-- get the date 2 month prior to today's date
Range("A1:AZ100000").AutoFilter field:=40, Criteria1:=">" & DQ, Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```